# Chrome "Take Heap Snapshot" never completes

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

### Summary:

I'm trying use Chrome's "Take Heap Snapshot" to track down a memory leak in some node.js code, but the act of taking a snapshot never completes.

Am I mis-using the tool somehow?

### Details:

Here's the node.js app:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var serialserver = require('./p5.serialserver');
serialserver.start();
console.log("p5.serialserver is running");
```

Here's how I invoke it, and what it prints out:

```
$ node --inspect ./p5serial
Debugger listening on port 9229.
Warning: This is an experimental feature and could change at any time.
To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome:
     chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@521e5b7e2b7cc66b4006a8a54cb9c4e57494a5ef/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:9229/node
p5.serialserver is running
```

In Chrome (Version 59.0.3071.115), running under OSX 10.12.6 (Sierra), I open the given URL and click on `Take Heap Snapshot`.  I see the icon in the left column which says:

```
Snapshot 1
Snapshotting...
```

... but even after waiting for ten minutes, the snapshot hasn't completed.  This is not a particularly large node application.

What am I missing?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/adminIntro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to successfully take a heap snapshot of the following:

```
const http = require('http');
const port = 3000;

const requestHandler = (request, response) => {  
  console.log(request.url);
  response.end(`you requested ${request.url}`);
};

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler);

server.listen(port, (err) => {  
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err);
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

Invoked via `node --inspect server.js`

Version info:

- macOS Sierra 10.12.6
- Chrome 62.0.3174.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)

Try downloading [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) and see if the problem is resolved in the latest version of Chrome.

If not, then there may be something going on with this serial server. Did you build it, or is it a library?

Comment: Chrome Canary capture the snapshot instantly.  I'll switch back to using it -- thanks for the suggestion.